# pydantic error during dockerfile execution

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fastapi, pydantic

I have a fastapi project which is running correctly with docker-compose and the normal run. However, when I try to execute the project with only the dockerfile an error occurs.
I HAVE TO read some config from .env and the variables are not updated with dockerfile.

The command fails

```
 docker run -p 8000:8000 --env-file ./.env test

    INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 68, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 456, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/./src/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.api.wiki.api import api_router
  File "/app/./src/api/wiki/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.api.wiki.endpoints import document, category, document_topic
  File "/app/./src/api/wiki/endpoints/document.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.api.dependencies import get_db
  File "/app/./src/api/dependencies.py", line 6, in <module>
    from src.core.config import settings
  File "/app/./src/core/config.py", line 61, in <module>
    settings = get_settings()
  File "/app/./src/core/config.py", line 58, in get_settings
    return Settings()
  File "pydantic/env_settings.py", line 36, in pydantic.env_settings.BaseSettings.__init__
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 15 validation errors for Settings
API_STR
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
PROJECT_NAME
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
DESCRIPTION
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
VERSION
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
SWAGGER_UI_OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URL
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
SECRET_KEY
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID
APP_CLIENT_ID
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
TENANT_ID
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
INSTANCE
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
DRIVER
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
SERVER
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
DATABASE
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
USERNAME
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
PASSWORD
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Dockerfile

```
COPY src /app/src
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./.env /app/.env

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "src.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--reload", "--port", "8000"]
```

I need some help to run the project.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us the content of your `./.env` file?

Comment: Why are you copying env file into image ? This is not good idea you only need to pass env file when you run container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to COPY your `.env` file in your Dockerfile

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

> https://dev.to/jakewitcher/using-env-files-for-environment-variables-in-python-applications-55a1